# Does Reactor Kafka Consumer starts consuming again / starts rebalancing after Termination ( doOnTermimate invoked)

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, project-reactor, reactor-kafka

Does Reactor Kafka Consumer starts consuming again / starts rebalancing after Termination ( doOnTermimate)

Trying to come up with a Reactor Kafka Consumer Health Service.
to know when the Consumer stops Consuming messages and not part of consumer group to rejoin again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after termination

You need a process supervisor to restart any terminated process. For example, a Kubernetes Pod restartPolicy

> starts rebalancing after Termination

Yes, all Kafka consumer groups rebalance after terminating *and restarting*.

---

This is not unique to Project Reactor.

Comment: So After Termination, Kafka Consumer doesn't start rebalancing/join the consumer group back on it's own. Without restarting the Pod ( using Pod restart policy)

Comment: Termination of one instance will rebalance the reminder of the group, if other instances exist. Termination is final, it will not rejoin on its own

Comment: if there are no Error handlers, then Kafka Consumer terminates and doOnTerminate life cycle method executes. and also if we get onErrorDropped does doOnTerminate handles that?

Comment: I do not use Reactor Kafka library, so cannot answer that. Non-Fatal errors should not terminate your code